# How to programmatically set Unidentified Networks to be a Private or Public Network Location on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, windows-10

Changing Ethernet or Wi-Fi connections to Private/Public is something very easy to be done. I can do that either from PowerShell or Registries.

But, is there a way of changing Unidentified Networks or Identifying Networks to Private/Public in a programmatically way on Windows 10 ? I would like to include this step into one of my projects.

I found this answer on the [sevenforums.com](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71408-unidentified-networks-set-private-public.html) , but it applies only to Windows 7.

Comment: I've left an answer. If your planning on dong it to remote computers, then you'll need to preform a remote connect to that computer using powershell (New-PSSession cmdlet) to update it.

Comment: Hi @NeoTheNerd. Thanks for your reply. 
My plan is to create a custom tool (small console app) which should be able to change:
- current Ethernet connection to Private
- Unidentified Networks to Private
- Identifying Networks to Private

Comment: And the fact is that I haven't found a way of changing the last 2 items to Private. Changing current Network to private is easy (as you described, I used the Set-NetConnectionProfile cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The General Command Is Using **Set-NetConnectionProfile** Cmdlet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netconnection/set-netconnectionprofile?view=windowsserver2019-ps

```
#Update Windows Firewall from Public to Private
Get-NetConnectionProfile | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
```

To Run The **Set-NetConnectionProfile** Cmdlet Command  On A Remote Computer

```
$server = "servername"
$RequestingServer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

[STRING] $LocalUser = "Administrator"
[STRING] $LocalPassword = "Password01"
$LocalSecurePassword = $LocalPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$LocalCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $LocalUser, $LocalSecurePassword

#Update Windows Firewall Remotely
$LocalSession = New-PSSession -Computername $Server -Credential $LocalCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session $LocalSession -ScriptBlock {

$AddServer = $Using:RequestingServer

    #Update Windows Firewall from Public to Private
    Get-NetConnectionProfile | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
    
    #Update Windows Firewall to allow remote WMI Access
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" new enable=yes
    
    #Update Trusted Hosts is not domain-joined and therefore must be added to the TrustedHosts list 
    Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $AddServer -Force
    
    #Update Windows Firewall to allow RDP
    Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"
    
    #Enable RDP : 1 = Disable ; 0 = Enable
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
}
```

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks a lot @NeoTheNerd !!
I have one completion to make: in case you deal with a "Unidentified Network" connection, then it is enough to call the next cmdlet in PowerShell in order to change its network category:
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Unidentified network" -NetworkCategory Private