# Script in PowerShell to enable all RDS services on a desktop windows platform

Tags: powershell, amazon-rds

I need to know what services are needed for RDS to work on a desktop windows platform and how can i write a powershell script to enable them all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Enabling Remote Desktop on Windows OS**

This is the registry key to enable / disable the remote desktop service on a workstation or server.

```
#Enable RDP : 1 = Disable ; 0 = Enable
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
```

As for scripts to preform this, look here...
[How to programmatically set Unidentified Networks to be a Private or Public Network Location on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260046/how-to-programmatically-set-unidentified-networks-to-be-a-private-or-public-netw/70261227#70261227)